# How to display only corresponding computed result and not all results for each row when using [tapply]

Tags: r, function, tapply

i'm having some issues on displaying the results. Basically i stored 3 vectors into a dataframe and perform some computation and store into a new vector before combining this new vector with the dataframe.

```
h=c(155,150,165,190,177)
w=c(85,90,72,99,55)
g=c("F","F","M","F","M")
df=data.frame(h,w,g)
row.names(df)=c("alpha","bravo","charlie","foxtrot","echo")
bmi=tapply(df$w,df$h,function(calc){(df$w/(df$h)^2)*10000})
cbind(df,bmi)
```

And the printed result is

```
        h  w g                                              bmi
alpha   155 85 F 35.37981, 40.00000, 26.44628, 27.42382, 17.55562
bravo   150 90 F 35.37981, 40.00000, 26.44628, 27.42382, 17.55562
charlie 165 72 M 35.37981, 40.00000, 26.44628, 27.42382, 17.55562
foxtrot 190 99 F 35.37981, 40.00000, 26.44628, 27.42382, 17.55562
echo    177 55 M 35.37981, 40.00000, 26.44628, 27.42382, 17.55562
```

However, what i want is only to display

```
         h  w g  bmi
alpha   155 85 F 35.37981 
bravo   150 90 F 40.00000
charlie 165 72 M 26.44628
foxtrot 190 99 F 27.42382
echo    177 55 M 17.55562
```

Comment: It looks like you don't need `tapply` here, just use `df$bmi = df$w / (df$h)^2) * 10000`. `tapply` is for group-level computations.

Comment: oh wow, it worked! But for learning sake, is it necessary / possible to use `tapply` for this question?

Comment: It is not advisable. You could construct a group variable where each row is it's own group and perform the operation that way, but it's unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: You can use sapply! try `bmi = sapply(df$h, function(calc){(df$w/(df$h)^2)*10000})[,1]` but it is not very efficient way to go about this

Comment: @AlexBraksator there is no need for any `*apply` function here.

Comment: Thanks guys for the advice!